# Parsing a set of JSON objects with jq

Tags: json, grep, jq

A have a big block of JSON l'm trying to parse, that looks basically like

```
{
  "order": [
    "hash1",
    "hash2"
  ],
  "posts": {
    "hash4": {
      "id": "hash4",
      "message": "lorem ipsem"
    },
    "hash5": {
      "id": "hash5",
      "message": "dolor sit amet"
    },
    "hash6": {
      "id": "hash6",
      "message": "consectetur adipiscing elit"
    }
  }
}
```

The way I've been handling this so far is to just grep for messages

```
$ grep 'message' jq_dat.json 
      "message": "lorem ipsem"
      "message": "dolor sit amet"
      "message": "consectetur adipiscing elit"
```

This works for my current purposes, but l'd like to know how to get the same effect with `jq`. I.e.

```
$ jq .posts.<something>.message < jq_dat.json
"lorem ipsem"
"dolor sit amet"
"consectetur adipiscing elit"
```

I've tried using `[]` and `{}` in place of `something`, but those both spit back compile errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have one too many dot

```
jq .posts[].message < jq_dat.json
```